# Query values that matche uid in Map of Lists Firestore - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

---

[image]

I need to fetch documents that `'uid', isEqualTo: 'IeXbRCpmB8ejUdYh7nn4IQ2HgUC3'`

Above list is containing maps.

How can I do this on flutter?

I tried below code but it's giving **No Data** as output.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('abc')
          .where('list.uid', isEqualTo: 'ijQS0rKB4aOJSoTKy1zvmy8O9me2')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(child: Text('Something wrong!'));
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        if (snapshot.data!.size == 0) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text('No Data'),
          );
        }

        return const Center(child: Text('Done'));
      },
    )
```

How do I perform this query?

Comment: You can't.  You will have to use one of the alternatives in the duplicates.

Comment: While you can query an array for complete matches (with `array-contains`), you can't query on a partial match of an item in an array. If you want to be able to query on just the UID, consider having an additional field (e.g. `listUIDs`) with just those values and then using `array-contains` on that.